# Strings: .replaceAll and .Substring: Practical example explaination?

Tags: java, string, substring, replaceall

What steps are actually happening within the following two methods? I have a rough understanding of what the methods are to do, but I do not know how.

Method 1:

```
public String processDiscardedLetters(String name) {
        return name.substring(0, 1)
                + name.substring(1).replaceAll("[aeihouwy]", "");
    }
```

Method 2:

```
public String processEquivalentLetters(String name) {
        name = name.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "a");
        name = name.replaceAll("[cgjkqsxyz]", "c");
        name = name.replaceAll("[bfpvw]", "b");
        name = name.replaceAll("[dt]", "d");
        name = name.replaceAll("[mn]", "m");
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Have you got any experience with regex?

Comment: No i do not, what is it?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: `[abc]` matches any one letter of "a", "b", or "c".

Comment: [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (RegEx) is very powerful way to search through strings. In particular to your question the `[]` checks for **any** of those characters inside of it, and replaces them. So if `name = "hello matey"` then the result of `name.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "a")` would be `"halla matay"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the examples use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to transform input.

The bracket syntax `[]` is a character class, which means that any character inside it will match with a part of the input.

In particular, doing a string replace with `[aeihouwy]` will replace all occurrences of any of the letters with the replacement string.

**Method 1**: Preserves the first letter regardless of what it is, and removes all occurrences of of the of the characters `aeihouwy` for the rest of the string.

To be more specific, Method 1 is doing the following steps.

1. Separate the original string into two parts: The first character and the rest of the String. This uses the `subString` method with arguments `0` and `1` to pull out the first character, and argument `1` to extract the part of the string starting at the second character and ending at end of string.
2. Use `replaceAll` to eliminate any of the characters `aeihouwy` from the second half of the string.
3. Join the strings together again.

**Method 2**: For your first example

```
    name = name.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "a"); // Replace of any of the letters `aeiou` with `a`  whereever they occur.
```

Comment: Wrong, the `substring` method **never** uses regular expressions.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, Did I say the substring method uses regular expressions?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, his method 1 also uses `replaceAll`. I did not mention substring at all.

Comment: Read the question, it asks about `substring` and `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0):

String's [`substring(startIndex, endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) methods actually takes a string from a start index (inclusive) to the end index (exclusive) of the string array (A string is a `CharSequence` which is a "string array"). As you are aware, array counts starts from 0 to N - 1. A [`substring(startIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) takes a string starting from `index` to the end of the string.

The [`replaceAll(String regularExpression, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method will replace a string based on the matched [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) criteria. If a portion of a string matches a regular expression criteria, it gets replaced by a replacement string.

The regular expression in `[` and `]` are called [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). These tell the regular expression engine to match only 1 out of those characters. So, if you have `[aeihouwy]`, the words like `grey` will match since it identified gr`[ey]` and gr`[e]`y as well as gre`[y]`. So, any mentioned words will be replaced with a blank string `""`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Example 1:
input: here are my
output: hr r m //replaced with '' (nothing)

Example 2 (first line):
input: cake is king xoxo
output: aaka as kang xoxo // replaced with 'a'
```

As you can see that the characters inside [] will be replaced with the character you write as 2nd parameter.

Comment: Surely the first method would always keep the 1st letter, therefore h should be the first letter in the output?

Comment: Sorry my bad, missed the subString part. Fixed.